# Header background image not resizing as I would expect - ideas?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a website that I am trying to make behave decently when a browser window is resized. For instance, I want the banner image to be resized when someone shrinks the browser window. The site is http://www.pfp-consortium.org

The banner on top is specified in CSS as

```
#rt-showcase .rt-container {
    border-bottom: 0px none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1200px;
    background: transparent url("/images/headerimgs/topimage.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center;
```

}

So I know the fixed width and height has to go. In reading numerous threads on this site, I tried various recommended approaches. I tried setting width (and max-width) to 100% and height to auto, which seems to be the accepted approach. Strangely, whenever I make height anything other than a px value, the image disappears!

Maybe some other aspect of the site is preventing the resizing happening as I would expect?

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Don't forget to accept if it did. If it didn't can you clarify more so we can assist?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.rt-container` is empty so when the height is auto (or anything except px) the div defaults to 0 height (empty). If you take that image out of the background image and make it an `<img>` tag then you can apply `width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;` and it will scale with the window correctly.